Why Android enforces me to use Hilt if I want to test @AndroidEntryPoint annotated classes (UI TEST) but hilt can not provide Activity object
I am trying to test a Main Activity class that is @AndroidEntryPoint using Hilt Testing in my Android application. The PermissionHelper class is defined as follows:
public class PermissionHelper {

    private final AppCompatActivity mActivity;

    @Inject
    public PermissionHelper(AppCompatActivity activity) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }

}

Hilt Testing Setup:
When using unit tests, Android Studio does not enforce the use of Hilt testing. However, for instrumented tests, it is mandatory to use Hilt testing. I created test module that replaces Activity component I provide the activity and permission helper as follows:
@Module
@TestInstallIn(components = [ActivityComponent::class], replaces = [ActivityModule::class])
class TestModule {
    @Provides
    @ActivityScoped
    fun provideActivityScenario(): ActivityScenario<MainActivity> {
        // Launch MainActivity
        return ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity::class.java)
    }

    @Provides
    @ActivityScoped
    fun provideAppCompatActivity(scenario: ActivityScenario<MainActivity>): Activity? {
        // Extract AppCompatActivity from ActivityScenario
        val activity = arrayOfNulls<MainActivity>(1)
        scenario.onActivity { a -> activity[0] = a }
        return activity[0]
    }

    @ActivityScoped
    @Provides
    fun providePermissionHelperFake(activity: Activity): PermissionHelperFake {
        return PermissionHelperFake(activity)
    }
}

Error Encountered:
when using test modules and replaces the activity module, I got the error that Activity is NULL and can not be provided, from where can I get activity object ?
  @UninstallModules(ActivityModule.class) // Uninstall the real PermissionModule
@HiltAndroidTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityTest {

    @Rule public HiltAndroidRule hiltRule = new HiltAndroidRule(this);

    @Inject PermissionHelperFake permissionHelper;

    @Inject LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    @Inject FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        hiltRule.inject();
    }

    @Test
    public void testDependencies() {
        assertNotNull(permissionHelper);
        assertNotNull(layoutInflater);
        assertNotNull(fragmentManager);

        // Your test code here
    }

My Findings is that Hilt can not provide activity or create activity even if I provide Activity from scenario, it can just provide context and it can just be used in backend testing,
But while using instrumented tests, Android studio is forcing me to use Hilt while launching main activity, since it is @AndroidEntryPoint, my use case test must also be @HiltAndroidTest,
Why then android enforces me to use hilt if it can not provide activity ?
Any idea or recommendation how can I start UI testing with @AndroidEntryPoint classes?
   error: [Dagger/Nullable] android.app.Activity    is not nullable, but is being provided by @Provides @dagger.hilt.android.scopes.ActivityScoped @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable android.app.Activity common.dependencyinjection.activity.TestModule.provideAppCompatActivity(androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario<.common.dependencyinjection.screens.main.MainActivity>)

error: [Dagger/DuplicateBindings] android.app.Activity is bound multiple times:
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements FragmentGetContextFix.FragmentGetContextFixEntryPoint,
rror: [Dagger/MissingBinding] android.app.Activity cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements FragmentGetContextFix.FragmentGetContextFixEntryPoint,


Have you tried to inject a Testing Activity?
